# Where's the error in my solution to Putnam 2022 A3?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

Question: A3 Let $p$ be a prime number greater than 5. Let $f(p)$ denote
the number of infinite sequences $a_1,a_2,a_3,...$ such that
$a_n \in \{1,2,..., p − 1\}$ and $a_n a_{n+2} \equiv 1 + a_{n+1}$ (mod $p$)
for all $n ≥ 1$. Prove that $f(p)$ is congruent to 0 or 2
(mod 5).

If $a_1$ and $a_2$ are each not $\equiv$ to 0 or -1, then I think the sequence should work. Accordingly, you have $p-2$ options for $a_1$ and $a_2$, and therefore you have $(p-2)^2$ sequences, which clearly doesn't agree with the requested result (congruency to 0 or 2 (mod 5)).

proof

Firstly, there is exactly one solution for $a_{n+2}$ in the recurrence relation, since we can divide both sides by $a_n$ freely since $a_n$ is relatively prime to our mod base. Therefore $a_1$ and $a_2$ determine the entire series.

Secondly, a sequence will not be infinite iff the solution for $a_{n+2}$ is 0 at some point, since this residue isn't allowed in our sequence. This is identical to saying no $a_{n+1} \equiv -1$ , since if this is true, then $a_{n+2} ≡ (a_{n+1}+1)/a_n$  will never be 0, since the numerator $a_{n+1}+1$ will never be 0. So we want to ensure no $a_{n+1}$ is ever ≡ -1 .

In general, if $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ are each not $\equiv$ to 0 or -1, then $(a_{n} + 1)(a_{n+1} + 1) \neq 0$. Dividing by $a_n$, we get

$(1 + 1/a_n)(a_{n+1}+1) \neq 0$

$1 + a_{n+1} + (a_{n+1}+1)/a_n \neq 0 $

$1 + a_{n+1} + a_{n+2} \neq 0$

meaning

$a_{n+2} + 1 \neq -a_{n+1}$

meaning

$a_{n+3}  ≡  (a_{n+2}+1)/a_{n+1} \neq -1$

Therefore if $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ are each not ≡ to 0 or -1, then $a_{n+3}$  is not congruent to 0 or -1.
So, we can prove that the infinite sequence exists recursively by arguing that if
$a_1, a_2$, and $a_3 \neq 0, -1$, then $a_4$ isn't as well, and $a_5$ isn't, and $a_6$, ...

Can anyone find the error?

Comment: This is too hard to read. Use mathjax please! -1

Comment: How would a sequence starting with $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = p-2$ look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition $1+a_{n+1} + a_{n+2} \neq 0 \pmod{p}$ only works for $n \geq 1$, hence it does not cover the case $1+a_1+a_2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$; in that situation, $a_3= p-1 $ and $a_4 = 0$, which is not allowed.